# How do you undo a deleted agent for a GOCD server?

Tags: go-cd, go-agent

I disabled/deleted a `GOCD` `go-agent`. It seems I can no longer attempt to register this `go-agent`, as it doesn't appear in the agents list on service start.

Is this agent getting blacklisted somewhere since it was deleted? Just tried to disable/delete another go-agent that was working just fine, and it also no longer appears in the list on service start.

I checked the `cruise-config.xml`, with no mentioned of the deleted agent. The UI doesn't show deleted agents either.

Answer (score 5):

If you *disable* an agent on in the GoCD's server agent administration page, it is shown grayed out at the end of the list. You can re-enable it.

If you *delete* and agent, GoCD truly forgets about it.

If you then, on an agent machine, start an agent that you had previously deleted, it'll show up in the agent list again in state `Pending`, and you have to enable it.

If the agent doesn't show up, it's worth checking the agent's log (`/var/log/go-agent/*.log`) and possibly the server's log if there are any cues about why the agent doesn't register.

Finally, you can try to delete `/var/lib/go-agent/config/` (make a backup first) on the agent. Restarting the agent then allocates a new agent UUID, so the GoCD server will see it as a new agent.